# валидация формы, накопление ошибок

Tags: php

пытаюсь в массиве вывести все ошибки которые были допущены, но в нем оказывается только одна, остальные выводит

```
if($nameLen<3 or $nameLen>100){

    $arr = [
    'name' => 'Название должно содержать от 3 до 100 символов',
    ];

    $err = false;
}
if($descriptionLen<3 or $descriptionLen>100){

    $arr = [
    'text' => 'Описание должно содержать от 3 до 100 символов',
    ];

    $err = false;
}

if($err == false){

    $array = array($arr);
    $this->error = $array;
    return false;
}
```

var_dump($this->error) выводит результат:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["text"]=> string(81) "Описание должно содержать от 3 до 100 символов" } }
```

Как сделать что бы в массив выводил все ошибки?

Comment: А что вы ожидали, __перезаписывая__ переменную `$arr`?

Comment: @u_mulder, как ее накопить и записать в итоговый результат?

Comment: $arr['name'] = "... $arr['text'] = "...

Comment: @Kirill, так заработало=)

Answer (score 0):

Просматривая ваш код, увидел использование `$this->errors` в контексте класса. Предлагаю свой вариант решения:

```php
/**
 * @var array $_errors
 */
private $_errors = [];

/**
 * Метод добавления новой ошибки для указанного поля.
 * @param string $field
 * @param string $message
 */
public function addError(string $field, string $message): void
{
    array_push($this->_errors[$field], $message);
}

/**
 * Проверка на существование каких-либо ошибок.
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasErrors(): bool
{
    return empty($this->_errors);
}

/**
 * Метод возвращения ошибок.
 * @return array
 */
public function getErrors(): array 
{
    return $this->_errors;
}
```

Comment: достаточно было $arr['name'] = "... $arr['text'] = добавить

Comment: Просто предложил реализацию) В обоих случаях оно будет верным. Вам решать как делать!

Comment: кстати, что это за записи такие, это точно на php???

Comment: Конечно! Ну если вы используете php >=7.0, то у вас будет работать данный код. Не пугайтесь, `: array` - это тип возвращаемого значения. А комментарии к методам и свойствам - обычный phpdoc.